# Why does this code freeze my WPF UI?

Tags: wpf, powershell

I am writing a Powershell script utilizing WPF with the methods shown here: http://learn-powershell.net/2012/10/14/powershell-and-wpf-writing-data-to-a-ui-from-a-different-runspace/.

I'm encountering an issue with the follow code freezing the UI as the "btnTest" button is clicked.  I'm guessing this is some sort of deadlock because one thread is attempting to access another thread's resources.  I hope there's some way around this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework,PresentationCore,WindowsBase
$global:syncHash = [Hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$syncHash.Host = $Host
$runSpace = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace()
$runSpace.ApartmentState,$runSpace.ThreadOptions = “STA”,”ReUseThread”
$runSpace.Open()
$runSpace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable(“syncHash”,$syncHash)
$cmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework,PresentationCore,WindowsBase,System.Windows.Controls
$syncHash.Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Parse(@”
       XAML goes here
“@)

$syncHash.btnTest = $global:syncHash.Window.FindName(“btnTest”)
$syncHash.txtText = $global:syncHash.Window.FindName(“txtTest”)

$syncHash.btnTest.Add_Click({
$syncHash.btnTest.IsEnabled = $false
$syncHash.Host.Runspace.Events.GenerateEvent(“btnTestClicked”, $syncHash.btnTest, $null, $null)
})

$syncHash.Window.ShowDialog()
})
$cmd.Runspace = $runSpace
$handle = $cmd.BeginInvoke()

# THIS CODE FREEZES THE UI
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier “btnTestClicked” -Action {
$global:syncHash.btnTest.Dispatcher.invoke([System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority]::Normal, [action]{$global:syncHash.btnTest.IsEnabled = $true}, $null, $null)
}
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need to interact with the form via PowerShell's engine event mechanism?

Comment: Keith, I have long running "tasks" that are locking up the UI and I would like to retrieve the result of the task and display it within a textbox in the UI.